# Are these legitimate rules/formula for integration without using the substitution method?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

**I'm talking about:**

**$\int(ax+b)^ndx=\frac{(ax+b)^{n+1}}{(n+1)(a)}$**

**$\int\frac{1}{ax+b}dx=\frac{1}{a}\ln(ax+b)$**

**$\int e^{ax+b}dx=\frac{e^{ax+b}}{a}$**

**$\int a^{ax+b}dx=\frac{a^{ax+b}}{(\ln|a|)(a)}$**

Of course, this only works for $(ax+b)$, not for other $f(x)$ with higher exponents like $x^2$ or $x^3$

**So for example if write my working as:**

\begin{align}
\int(2x+8)^3dx&=\frac{(2x+8)^4}{(4)(2)} \\
&=\frac{1}{8}(2x+8)^4
\end{align}

... based on the rule above

I just want to know if such working/rule applied is actually acceptable without using the substitution method.

Comment: This is minor, but in each of your integrals you need to include the constant of integration (generally written as $C$ - as I'm sure you are familiar with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm going to prove/disprove each one of these bad boys.

**#1:**
$$I=\int(ax+b)^n\mathrm{d}x$$
Substitution: $u=ax+b\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}a=\mathrm{d}x$
$$I=\frac1a\int u^n\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I=\frac{(ax+b)^{n+1}}{a(n+1)}$$
**Correct**

**#2:**
$$I=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{ax+b}$$
substitution: $u=ax+b\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}a=\mathrm{d}x$
$$I=\frac1a\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}u$$
$$I=\frac1a\ln|u|$$
$$I=\frac1a\ln|ax+b|, \qquad a\neq0$$
**You forgot the $|$ bars, but otherwise correct**

**#3:**
$$I=\int e^{ax+b}\mathrm{d}x$$
substitution: $u=ax+b\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}a=\mathrm{d}x$
$$I=\frac1a\int e^u\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I=\frac1ae^u$$
$$I=\frac1ae^{ax+b}$$
**Correct**

**#4:**
$$I=\int a^{ax+b}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int e^{(ax+b)\ln a}\mathrm{d}x$$
substitution: $u=(ax+b)\ln a\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{a\ln a}=\mathrm{d}x$
$$I=\frac1{a\ln a}\int e^u\mathrm{d}u$$
$$I=\frac1{a\ln a}e^u$$
$$I=\frac{e^{(ax+b)\ln a}}{a\ln a}$$
$$I=\frac{a^{ax+b}}{a\ln a}$$
$$I=\frac{a^{ax+b-1}}{\ln a}$$
**Basically correct**

As you can see, these all require very simple substitutions to prove. And yes, once you have established a formula you can use that formula and you don't have to go through the work of actually integrating. Example: you don't go through the process of proving 
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\ln|x|$$
every time you have to integrate it, do you? Of course not. By the same token, the formulas derived above can be used instead of going through the steps of integrating every time.

Answer (score 1):

The second formula is false, the other formulas are correct.

The correct second formula reads as follows: for $a \ne 0$ we have $\int\frac{1}{ax+b}dx=\frac{1}{a}ln(ax+b)$.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, my bad. So if such formulas are legit, do you know why is it that every answers online uses the substitution method instead of a more straightforward way of getting the answer?          
https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-antiderivative-of-2x-1-3 https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-integrals-of-2x-1-%C2%B2